# Scala connection pool library?

Tags: java, scala, connection-pooling

I'm trying to use Squeryl in a new Scala project. This is my first project in Scala, so I'm looking for a good Scala library to handle connection pooling. Of course I might as well use a Java library. What would be a best fit for SQueryl? Amongst java libraries I'm considering DBCP, C3P0, Proxool and BoneCP, being BoneCP a serious candidate looking at their benchmarks.

Comment: I found BoneCP to be flakey, and DBCP to be more stable... but YMMV.  BoneCP website didn't even work half of the time...

Comment: I have found DBCP to be most flakey of all.

Comment: So, if both BoneCP and DBCP are flakey, no comments about Proxool and a good comment about C3P0 I think I'll give C3P0 a try!!

Comment: Can you justify finding BoneCP being "flaky" ? That's certainly not the feedback I get not to mention there is exactly 1 open bug for now. Re website you can blame the host provider -- they promised 99%+ uptime but that's simply not true.

Comment: BoneCP gave my application (spring batch based) random hangs, and 10% less speed than DBCP. I have no skin in the game either way, I don't contribute to either project... just in my personal high performance project, DBCP has worked well, and bone CP was not good. In other cases it may be reverse, doesn't take long to test it out...

Comment: What version was this? I've yet to receive a report claiming the pool caused hangs and certainly no benchmark showing dbcp was faster under any circumstance. Honestly puzzled here, not trying to pick a fight :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used C3P0 in production for many years, always been rock solid for me. Watch out with your DB driver tho, they can be very flaky.

Comment: Ok thank you. Well I'm planning to use MariaDB which is a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

Comment: @DrKarl - any reason why you want something like MySql in the first place? voltdb and luciddb are both far better performing if you know for certain how the db will be used. PostgreSQL is all round better as a general purpose db, and NoSQL solutions are better for certain data structures. If you're moving away from MySql anyway then you'd be wise to properly consider all the options.

Comment: @Kevin - I know about VoltDB thanks to Hacker News, but I didn't know about LucidDB, thank you for the hint! I haven't considered NoSQL for this project and PostgreSQL could be another good option. Anyway I had read good things about MariaDB and Drizzle, and also good things about Firebird...

Comment: @Viktor Klang It is interesting that BoneCp was choosed by PlayFramework .Playframework is give interesting aspects about future such as Akka :), Scala, BoneCp, Config etc..

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog post about db connection pooling with slick you may find useful:

http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but to keep the answer current, if you need a connection pool and you're writing an application that runs on the JVM, I suggest [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).