# Connection pooling in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Is there an easy way to use a DB connection pool with scala's [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)?

Comment: My guess is that if you use it from within the Play Framework 2.1 you get connection pooling for free. Play Framework uses [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) as it's underlying library

Comment: Similar question: [Scala connection pool library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080707/scala-connection-pool-library)

Comment: I'm not asking **if** there is a pooling library in the JVM world. I'm asking about the easiest way to use (any) one with Slick. Thanks

Comment: Slick requires a session to be available. You could get one from the database object `Database.forDataSource(ds: DataSource)`. You can use the `createSession` or `withSession` methods from the database object. The datasource is the one you request from a pool library.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use `Apache Commons DBCP` for this. Basically, you simply create a `DataSource`, that encapsulates the pooling details, and pass that `DataSource` to Slick:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

val dataSource: DataSource = {
  val ds = new BasicDataSource
  ds.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver")
  ds.setUsername("SA")
  ds.setPassword("")
  ds.setMaxActive(20);
  ds.setMaxIdle(10);
  ds.setInitialSize(10);
  ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS")
  new java.io.File("target").mkdirs // ensure that folder for database exists
  ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/db/db")
  ds
}

// test the data source validity
dataSource.getConnection().close()

// get the Slick database that uses the pooled connection
val database = Database.forDataSource(dataSource)
```

This example uses HSQLDB, but can be easily adapted to any other database.

Full example is [here](https://github.com/Rogach/template/blob/master/lift/src/main/scala/DB.scala#L12) (you can clone the project, and run `sbt run` in lift/ directory to see it working).

Answer (score 22):

For completion I ended up writing a blog post about this:

http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html

Comment: Anytime! It was contributed to slick-examples (https://github.com/slick/slick-examples) by the way

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.4 now uses HikariCP which looks really nice: 
https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsJDBC

Answer (score -1):

It appears as though the later version of play pool configured connections - see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/SettingsJDBC