# How to use DRILLTHROUGH with Mondrian OLAP?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

How to I use `DRILLTHROUGH` queries with Mondrian? For example, this MDX query

```
DRILLTHROUGH
SELECT
  measures.MEMBERS ON 0
FROM
  events
```

generates an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: mondrian.olap.DrillThrough cannot be cast to mondrian.olap.Query
    at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement$1.execute(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:362)
    at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement$1.execute(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:360)
    at mondrian.server.Locus.execute(Locus.java:87)
    at mondrian.server.Locus.execute(Locus.java:72)
    at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement.parseQuery(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:356)
    at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement.executeOlapQuery(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:346)
```

In code, I am passing the MDX string to the statement as follows:

```
OlapConnection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string).unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
connection.createStatement.executeOlapQuery(mdx);
```

I have also experimented with calling `drillThrough` on a `Cell`, but this results in exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`. Perhaps I am not managing connections properly? See my other question: [Mondrian OLAP connection management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743156/mondrian-olap-connection-management).

Answer (score 2):

Drillthrough operations will return a ResultSet (implementing the regular JDBC API), so you need to use this instead:

```
olapConnection.createStatement().executeQuery(String mdx)
```

Comment: Thank you. So, by using the JDBC API I am implicitly operating a lower level of abstraction. If my intent is to expose MDX to my client with support for DRILLDOWN, what's the recommended approach? Can I parse the MDX first, and then examine the AST to determine whether to use the OLAP or JDBC API?

Comment: Well, since DRILLTHROUGH is a reserved keyword, it is safe to assume that if it appears unquoted/unescaped, then the query is a drillthrough.